# Modernizr and descendants selector?

Tags: css, performance, html, modernizr

According to **[mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Writing_Efficient_CSS#Avoid_the_descendant_selector.21)** :

> The descendant selector is the most expensive selector in CSS. It is
>   dreadfully expensive—especially if the selector is in the Tag or
>   Universal Category.

When Modernizr is up , it adds all the non supported classes to the `html` tag.

Meaning he can later do :

```
.myNotSupportedClass .myLastDiv   <-- notice descendants selecotr[ ]
{
  color:red;
}
```

But this is <strike>absolutely slow operation</strike> an operation which can be optimized.... which has to go through all the DOM tree in order to find the div.
I know there isn't another way  of doing it , but still :

1) **they could have** added those classes to the `body/form` which is closer to the elements. soo there will be less of searching.

Or am I wrong ...,?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But this is *absolutely slow operation*

Eh.

> **they could have** added those classes to the `body/form` which is closer to the elements. soo there will be less of searching.

`body`: how much less searching? 1 level less? How much of a difference does that make?

`form`: not every page has a form, and pages can have *more than one* form. The `form` element itself can be placed anywhere in the page body too, so the elements that should be affected by selectors in Modernizr class context may very well be unrelated to it, making searching *completely impossible*.

Do whatever you like, but since Modernizr chooses to place classes on the `html` element, write contextual selectors that make use of those classes and the descendant selector. If you're that obsessive about descendant selector performance, you have the choice not to use Modernizr and lose all the feature detection goodness it brings.

*Why* it chooses to place classes on the `html` element is anybody's guess. It could have been the most convenient element to place them on.

Comment: just want to know what was behind this decision of html rather than body.

Comment: Then you need to state that clearly instead of rambling, which is what I notice frequently occurs in your questions.

Comment: @RoyiNamir Simply, *no*. It just doesn't matter. Do you really think that **one level** up (kind of equivalent to one 'CSS operation') the DOM tree will be the difference between a snappy and a stupidly slow page? Adding the classes to `<html>` makes more sense intuitively, because `<html>` is more global, more inclusive, ...

You get the point.

Comment: @RoyiNamir Note that you can simply edit Modernizr's code to add the classes to `<body>` instead, if you insist. Shouldn't be hard at all.

Comment: With all the respect , You dont have to like my questions. If you think my questions are ramblings , please specify it in the question you saw , so I could phrase it better. ( instead of writing insulting comment as you did in your last comment. you are a moderator  , respect your status). ( and I _did ask_ a specific question).

Comment: @RoyiNamir 'Rambling' isn't insulting.

Comment: nevermind. read the _whole comment sentence_ in my POV and see that im right .

Comment: p.s. they could also put in the form...no ? that could lead to >1 ,>2 ,>3 levels.

Comment: @Royi Namir: Not every page has a form.

Comment: @RoyiNamir Here's a version of Modenrizr that'll add the classes to `body` instead of `html`: [little link](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=N0e0XCYX). Basically just changed `docElement = document.documentElement` to `docElement = document.body`.

Comment: @Abody97 Your linked script doesn't work: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null `